# Keras LSTM + TensorFlow and a number sequence (improve loss)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequence, lstm

first of all, I'm running with the following setup:

- Running on windows 10
- Python 3.6.2
- TensorFlow 1.8.0
- Keras 2.1.6

I'm trying to predict, or at least guesstimate the following number sequence:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJRPPx (limited to 20,000 for testing), the full sequence contains about one million records.

**And here is the code (run.py)**

```
import lstm
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_results(predicted_data, true_data):
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(true_data, label='True Data')
    plt.plot(predicted_data, label='Prediction')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def plot_results_multiple(predicted_data, true_data, prediction_len):
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(true_data, label='True Data')
    #Pad the list of predictions to shift it in the graph to it's correct start
    for i, data in enumerate(predicted_data):
        padding = [None for p in range(i * prediction_len)]
        plt.plot(padding + data, label='Prediction')
        plt.legend()
    plt.show()

#Main Run Thread
if __name__=='__main__':
    global_start_time = time.time()
    epochs  = 10
    seq_len = 50

    print('> Loading data... ')

    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = lstm.load_data('dice_amplified/primeros_20_mil.csv', seq_len, True)

    print('> Data Loaded. Compiling...')

    model = lstm.build_model([1, 50, 100, 1])

    model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size = 512,
        nb_epoch=epochs,
        validation_split=0.05)

    predictions = lstm.predict_sequences_multiple(model, X_test, seq_len, 50)
    #predicted = lstm.predict_sequence_full(model, X_test, seq_len)
    #predicted = lstm.predict_point_by_point(model, X_test)        

    print('Training duration (s) : ', time.time() - global_start_time)
    plot_results_multiple(predictions, y_test, 50)
```

**I have tried to:**

- increase and decrease epochs.
- increase and decrease batch size.
- amplify the data.

The following plot represents:

- epochs  = 10
- batch_size = 512
- validation_split = 0.05

[image: Keras plot]

**As well, as far as I understand, the loss should be decreasing with more epochs? Which doesn't seem to be happening!**

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
> Loading data...
> Data Loaded. Compiling...
> Compilation Time :  0.03000473976135254
Train on 17056 samples, validate on 898 samples
Epoch 1/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 31s 2ms/step - loss: 29927.0164 - val_loss: 289.8873
Epoch 2/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 29s 2ms/step - loss: 29920.3513 - val_loss: 290.1069
Epoch 3/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 29s 2ms/step - loss: 29920.4602 - val_loss: 292.7868
Epoch 4/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 27s 2ms/step - loss: 29915.0955 - val_loss: 286.7317
Epoch 5/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 26s 2ms/step - loss: 29913.6961 - val_loss: 298.7889
Epoch 6/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 26s 2ms/step - loss: 29920.2068 - val_loss: 287.5138
Epoch 7/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 28s 2ms/step - loss: 29914.0650 - val_loss: 295.2230
Epoch 8/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 25s 1ms/step - loss: 29912.8860 - val_loss: 295.0592
Epoch 9/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 28s 2ms/step - loss: 29907.4067 - val_loss: 286.9338
Epoch 10/10
17056/17056 [==============================] - 46s 3ms/step - loss: 29914.6869 - val_loss: 289.3236
```

**Any recommendations? How could I improve it? Thanks!**

**Lstm.py contents:**

```
import os
import time
import warnings
import numpy as np
from numpy import newaxis
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' #Hide messy TensorFlow warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") #Hide messy Numpy warnings

def load_data(filename, seq_len, normalise_window):
    f = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    data = f.decode().split('\n')

    sequence_length = seq_len + 1
    result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        result.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])

    if normalise_window:
        result = normalise_windows(result)

    result = np.array(result)

    row = round(0.9 * result.shape[0])
    train = result[:int(row), :]
    np.random.shuffle(train)
    x_train = train[:, :-1]
    y_train = train[:, -1]
    x_test = result[int(row):, :-1]
    y_test = result[int(row):, -1]

    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))  

    return [x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test]

def normalise_windows(window_data):
    normalised_data = []
    for window in window_data:
        normalised_window = [((float(p) / float(window[0])) - 1) for p in window]
        normalised_data.append(normalised_window)
    return normalised_data

def build_model(layers):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(
        input_shape=(layers[1], layers[0]),
        output_dim=layers[1],
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[2],
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=layers[3]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    print("> Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model

def predict_point_by_point(model, data):
    #Predict each timestep given the last sequence of true data, in effect only predicting 1 step ahead each time
    predicted = model.predict(data)
    predicted = np.reshape(predicted, (predicted.size,))
    return predicted

def predict_sequence_full(model, data, window_size):
    #Shift the window by 1 new prediction each time, re-run predictions on new window
    curr_frame = data[0]
    predicted = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        predicted.append(model.predict(curr_frame[newaxis,:,:])[0,0])
        curr_frame = curr_frame[1:]
        curr_frame = np.insert(curr_frame, [window_size-1], predicted[-1], axis=0)
    return predicted

def predict_sequences_multiple(model, data, window_size, prediction_len):
    #Predict sequence of 50 steps before shifting prediction run forward by 50 steps
    prediction_seqs = []
    for i in range(int(len(data)/prediction_len)):
        curr_frame = data[i*prediction_len]
        predicted = []
        for j in range(prediction_len):
            predicted.append(model.predict(curr_frame[newaxis,:,:])[0,0])
            curr_frame = curr_frame[1:]
            curr_frame = np.insert(curr_frame, [window_size-1], predicted[-1], axis=0)
        prediction_seqs.append(predicted)
    return prediction_seqs
```

**Addendum:**

At nuric suggestion I modified the model as following:

```
def build_model(layers):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(layers[1], layers[0]), output_dim=layers[1], return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(layers[2], return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=layers[3]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    print("> Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model
```

Still a bit lost on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you normalise the input, you don't normalise the output. The LSTM by default has a `tanh` output which means you will have a limited feature space, ie the dense layer won't be able to regress to large numbers.

You have a fixed length numerical input `(50,)`, directly pass that to Dense layers with `relu` activation and will perform better on regression tasks, something simple like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

For regression it is also preferable to use `l2` [regularizers](https://keras.io/regularizers/) instead of Dropout because you are not really feature extracting for classification etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nuric, but I'm a bit new into this... could you explain a bit further with code examples? I get the idea, but I'm not even sure where to start. Thanks again!

Comment: I would recommend researching the deep learning regression models and look at how they differ from classification problems. It's possible you might not need a deep learning approach, a random forest like [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might work better.

Comment: Thanks @nuric, problem is that I'm totally clueless with Random Forest, even more than deep learning. I tried to modify the model, as I understood, adding the 3 Dense layers you mentioned, I probably should remove some of the previous layers... Regarding xgboost, I'll start reading right away.

Comment: By any chance, do you know any good tutorial I could use as reference? the only one I found is here: https://www.quantinsti.com/blog/forecasting-markets-using-extreme-gradient-boosting-xgboost/ that uses one unique sequence, but it's all written on R... something similar using python would be the best.

Comment: This [post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/) might help.